# DPLYR filter not working within a user defined function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to create a function that filters an order universe by a value in a 
brand code column and return a distinct list of order numbers which is used to  filter the same universe by the resulting list of order number.

This second 
filtering of the universe will be grouped by brand code and count the number of 
occurrences of each brandcode.

Here is the code to create a sample order universe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

order_number   <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4")
item_brand_code <- 
c("ab","bb","cb","ab","uy","ik","ab","uy","sq","xx","xy","xz")
orderuniverse<-tibble(order_number,item_brand_code)
```

Here is the code that creates the result I am looking for

```
orderuniverse %>% 
filter(item_brand_code == "ab")%$%
unique(order_number)%>%  
as_tibble()%$%
###gets unique orders with item_brand_code of interest
filter(orderuniverse, order_number %in% .$value)%>%
group_by(item_brand_code)%>%
summarise(brandcode_count=n())%>%as.tibble%>%
arrange(desc(brandcode_count))
#filters orderuniverse to unique list of order_number with item_brandcode of 
#interest and groups by and counts number of times item_brandcode occurs
```

Resulting in

```
     item_brand_code      brandcode_count
              <chr>            <int>
1              ab               3
2              uy               2
3              bb               1
4              cb               1
5              ik               1
6              sq               1
```

When the above code is used to create a function it appears the second filter does not work inside the function.

Function code

```
brand_affinity<- function(dt,bcode,odnumber){
       group_by<-enquo(bcode)


       dt %>% 
       filter(bcode == "ab")%$%
       unique(odnumber)%>%  
       as_tibble()%$%
       filter(dt, odnumber %in% .$value)%>%
       group_by(!!group_by)%>%
       summarise(brandcode_count=n())%>%as.tibble%>%
       arrange(desc(brandcode_count))

}

affinity(orderuniverse,orderuniverse$item_brand_code,orderuniverse$order_number)
```

Results in

```
    item_brand_code      brandcode_count
    <chr>                    <int>
1    ab                        3
2    uy                        2
3    bb                        1
4    cb                        1
5    ik                        1
6    sq                        1
7    xx                        1
8    xy                        1
9    xz                        1
```

This is the result if there was not a filter on the order_number column

Is there some way the filter function needs to be used withing a function that I am missing?

Comment: it seems it would be better to rewrite your code in simple chunks, do you really need to pass as parameters some columns of your first input ? bcode is not a column name, you could use it as a string if you used `filter_` but you'd have to pass it as a string `"item_brand_code"` not a column. `unique(odnumber)` has nothing to to with pipe chain, as `odnumber` is not a column of dt, etc

Comment: your code is indeed not very easy to understand but it's most likely an issue with evaluation. Basically the same why you did the enquo für group_by. I'd try `!!group_by` inside filter instead of `bcode`. btw, verry bad practice to call your objects the same as a function (group_by). ;)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper the issue was with the unique(odnumber). I changed to unique(order_number) and I am getting the correct results. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: happy to help:)